# Should I enable or disable mysql query_cache for Magento?

Tags: mysql, magento, query-cache

I run Magento 1.9 and when I run mysql tuner script, it asks me to disable `query_cache` with

```
query_cache_size (=0)
 query_cache_type (=0)
```

But a lot of tutorials on the web suggest otherwise, to enable `query_cache` for Magento. I'm confused? Which way should I follow?

My store is running on server with `64GB Ram`. It doesn't have a lot of traffic and Read > Write.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL 8.0 and later have REMOVED Query Cache entirely, this should be a clue to DISABLE Query Cache (to encourage higher quality development - better response time).